# questions on SLURM configuration or setup

Tags: discussion

Are questions on setting up and configuring [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/) on an HPC cluster on topic for this site?  The particular question I have in mind is getting SLURM to work well with the license manager for proprietary FEA codes such as NASTRAN and ANSYS.

If not, what SE site do you think would be most appropriate?

Comment: You could try here, but you might be better off trying the SLURM mailing list.

Comment: I agree with Aron:  I've found that software specific questions are generally best handled by a user mailing list, but it is certainly within the scope of our website to ask a question about it.